# Identifying functional groups

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I've spent a few days googling functional groups and reading my text assigned on organic functional groups. I'm understanding very little and I just need a little clarification. I understand that at the top right and bottom left, the hexagon structure signifies an aromatic, right?

**Top Left**: My first guess was carboxylic acid, but with further googling, I now think it's an amide, because it contains nitrogen and oxygen?

**Top Right**: Since the hexagon is aromatic, I know it can only be the last three choices, but I'm going with C because the $\ce{-NH2}$ is not connected to an oxygen.

**Bottom Left**: Because of the $\ce{Br}$, I know it's a bromide and, assuming that my thinking is correct with aromatic, the answer should be B.

But the **bottom right**, I am not sure what exactly to look at here to even guess, besides that it is not an aromatic ring.

To show that I've tried the last one, all I can find is that an alkane is $\ce{CH4}$, alkene is $\ce{H2C=CH2}$, and an alkyne is $\ce{HC#CH}$ and, the aromatic being the hexagon structure, I'm unable to grasp/understand which one the last group would fall into.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you.

Comment: @alyssa Is it multiple choice test?

Comment: No, it's not a test or homework, these questions are coming from my book, so I can be more prepared for our final in a month. The functional groups just make no sense to me.

Comment: Basically anything in this format is categorized as *homework*. It doesn't need to be homework itself. Self-study questions, puzzles etc. also count as homework. Regarding your edit, I'm really inclined to vote to reopen, but you've shown no evidence of your research. You shouldn't say *I Googled but I couldn't find anything.* that isn't helpful at all. You should say *I Googled for blah blah, but it said bladiblah. so I can't understand the **di** in bladiblah. can you help me understand?* Do as so and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_group

Comment: This is much improved and it is clearer where your concerns are, asides from what @Mithoron linked to, here is another http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_With_a_Biological_Emphasis/Chapter_01%3A_Chapter_1%3A_Introduction_to_organic_structure_and_bonding_I/Section_1.4%3A_Functional_groups_and_organic_nomenclature

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm still just extremely confused on the last one, as I can't find anything provided on either of the links shared to give me an answer that I can understand and know is correct. I'm leaning towards Alkane, because it's closest, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Alkanes have only single bonds alkenes also double, alkynes triple, so what you think? Otherwise your answers are quite ok.

Comment: Basically, on the last one, list out what you see. As Mithoron stated, if you ONLY see single bonds, then alkane (CH4, C2H6, C3H8 etc...). If you see anything else, then it is usually classified otherwise since other functional groups are usually more meaningful for chemical reactions. Do you see any other bonds? Do you see a ring?

Comment: Okay, so based off of both of your explanations, it isn't an Alkane? Because of the H3C - CH?

Comment: Do you see the double bond? Two lines. I'll bring up some examples of alkenes. Search up examples such as propene, butene etc. In fact, the very compound is butene. The key is to look at the whole structures and list out what you see. Yes, there is the alkane PORTION but the fact that there is a double bond transforms its classification into alkene. it's sort of like the saying "one bad apple makes the whole lot rotten". Usually, in noting functional groups, you ignore the simple, saturated carbon chain (as in the alkane portion with only single bonds and CH bonds, no double)

Comment: The thing that looks like an equal sign? I was reading this as H3C - CH = CH2.. so, now I'm guessing that's wrong too. I told you guys the functional group is impossible for me to grasp!

Comment: Yes, the thing that looks like an equal sign signifies that it is a double bond. Three lines means triple. One line= 1 bond. 2 line = 2 bond. 3 line = 3 bond. And That's it. I doubt you'll every see 4 and more

Comment: Also, a trick for identifying alkane, alkene, and alkyne if you are more mathematically inclined is to use the general formula: CnH2n+2 for alkane, CnH2n for alkene, and CnH2n-2 for alkyne (related to the so-called degrees of unsaturation). *This does not account for multiple bonds, cyclic structures etc. and should be taken with caution* As you see 4. is C3H6. Also, you should note that alkenes and alkynes require at least 2 carbons

Comment: So the correct answer for this is Alkene because of the =?  I was basing the rest of my answers off what I previously said, so could you check those too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25440/discussion-between-andy-and-alyssa).

Answer (score 7):

Some pointers:

> the hexagon structure signifies an aromatic

Not quite. The hexagon structure depicted with **alternating carbon-carbon double and single bonds** is aromatic. It is called [benzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene) and is very commonly encountered in organic chemistry. It can be represented by two resonance structures as shown below and is sometimes also represented with a circle inside a ring of singly bonded carbons to show the delocalised $\pi$ system.

[image]

However, the are other molecules depicted as hexagons which are not aromatic such as cyclohexane.

[image]

Additionally, there are other molecules which are aromatic which are not benzene, and many which are not hexagonal but you probably won't come across these at an introductory level.

> My first guess was carboxylic acid, but with further googling, I'm now thinking it's an amide, because it contains nitrogen and oxygen

You are correct that it is an amide. The amide functional group contains a nitrogen adjacent to a carbon-oxygen **double** bond. The carboxylic acid group is similar but the nitrogen is replaced by an $\ce{-OH}$ group. Amides can be primary, secondary or tertiary depending on the number of carbons that are bonded to the nitrogen.

[image]

> alkane is $\ce{CH4}$, alkene is $\ce{H2C=CH2}$, and an alkyne is $\ce{HC#CH}$

These are the simplest example of alkanes, alkenes and alkynes. They are called methane, ethene and ethyne respectively. However, there are more complicated molecules involving these functional groups. In general, alkanes have only carbons-carbon **single** bonds and carbon-hydrogen single bonds. Alkenes are distinguished by having a carbon-carbon **double** bond denoted by two lines between the two carbons which look like an equals sign. Alkynes have a carbon-carbon **triple** bond which is denoted by three lines between the carbons. Therefore, your example is an alkene.

Comment: If the left compound of the three molecule you have draw had a halogen atom in the carbon chain could we still call it amide? I mean do we name a functional group by looking locally or by looking in the whole molecule

Answer (score 1):

The bottom right compound is an alkene.

There are no atoms other than $\ce{C}$ and $\ce{H}$ present, so you can rule out most functional groups straight away. The **double bond makes the compound an alkene.** The name of the compound is propene.